# Microsoft Bookings: How do i get an event if a new Appointment is scheduled

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-booking

We are using Microsoft Bookings to schedule events for our Customer Service (multiple users).

Therefor we would like to get an event when a new appointment is scheduled and pass it to Teams, our ASP.NET Web App or Power Apps.

Is there any Event/Webhook calling FROM Bookings which can trigger this?

To make this clear: we want an Event FROM Bookings TO our App.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see for events to be delivered when appointments are created is through Change Notifications but Currently MS Graph does not support change notifications for Bookings resources.

Consider creating a feature request for it in the [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so that the Engineering team may implement it in future.